# Convert timecode to seconds

Tags: javascript, time

I'm having problems changing a timecode into frames using JavaScript.
running at 30 fps we get

```
"00:00:01:00" = 30 frames
```

So far so good, only I check the number of seconds at it gets converted to this:

[image]

Firstly Not sure what's going on there?!
It's been pointed out that I had \f instead of \nf.

Secondly
The frames returned is incorrect.
1 minute should be 1800 seconds not 1800000

Bonus points if you can tell me if that's an Ankh or not.

```
// set the frame rate or Frame Rat as we like to call him
var frameRat = 30 // fps
var numOfFrames = 60 // animation frame count
var animTime = "00:01:00:00" // time code

var a = convertTimeToFrames(animTime, frameRat);
var result = animTime + " at " + frameRat + " fps\n = " + a + " frames.";
alert(result);



function convertTimeCodeToSeconds(timeString, framerate)
{

  var timeArray = timeString.split(":");
  var hours   = timeArray[0] * 60 * 60;
  var minutes = timeArray[1] * 60;
  var seconds = timeArray[2];
  var frames  = timeArray[3]*(1/framerate);
  var str = "h:" + hours + "\nm:" + minutes + "\ns:" + seconds + "\f:" + frames;
  alert(str)
  var totalTime = hours + minutes + seconds + frames;

  //alert(timeString + " = " + totalTime)
  return totalTime;
}

function convertTimeToFrames(timeString, framerate)
{
  var secs = convertTimeCodeToSeconds(timeString, framerate);
  return secs * framerate;
}
```

Comment: You have `\f:` instead of `\nf:` in your string. Is this what you mean?

Comment: What exactly is the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing operations between numbers and chars. Convert all values to Numbers after the split as follows:

```
// set the frame rate or Frame Rat as we like to call him
var frameRat = 30 // fps
var numOfFrames = 60 // animation frame count
var animTime = "00:01:00:00" // time code

var a = convertTimeToFrames(animTime, frameRat);
var result = animTime + " at " + frameRat + " fps\n = " + a + " frames.";
alert(result);



function convertTimeCodeToSeconds(timeString, framerate)
{

  var timeArray = timeString.split(":");
  var hours   = parseInt(timeArray[0]) * 60 * 60;
  var minutes = parseInt(timeArray[1]) * 60;
  var seconds = parseInt(timeArray[2]);
  var frames  = parseInt(timeArray[3])*(1/framerate);
  var str = "h:" + hours + "\nm:" + minutes + "\ns:" + seconds + "\nf:" + frames;
  alert(str)
  var totalTime = hours + minutes + seconds + frames;

  //alert(timeString + " = " + totalTime)
  return totalTime;
}

function convertTimeToFrames(timeString, framerate)
{
  var secs = convertTimeCodeToSeconds(timeString, framerate);
  return secs * framerate;
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case. `alert(typeof frames)` came back with number

Comment: `parseInt(n)` here should be replaced with `parseInt(n, 10)` to avoid unintended interpretation as octal.